# Intellisense not displaying all class definitions for libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

I'm using the visual studio IDE for this project (it has python 3.x). I tried installing `requests` and `lxml` with `pip` (for a web scraper) and I managed to install it, import it, and wrote this line:

```
__page = requests.get("www.google.com")
```

then I try to do

```
__page.content()
```

but apparently there is no definition for that. And this isn't the only package that does this. It also happens for `lxml`, `beautifulsoup`.

Any fix for this?

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fou74.jpg

Comment: What error do you specifically get?

Comment: .content just doesnt exist - https://imgur.com/a/wVerZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__page.text()` doesn't look like a function, it looks like an attribute, ie `__page.text`.

From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text:

> text
>
> > Content of the response, in unicode.
> >
> > If Response.encoding is None, encoding will be guessed using chardet.
> >
> > The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the encoding, you should set r.encoding appropriately before accessing this property.

Comment: Try to `print(__page.text)`. Sometimes `Intellisense` doesn't pick things up.